# How to crop an UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextview

I would like to have two UITextViews, one in the background and one in the front. Is there any possibility to crop 50% of the one in the foreground so that you can see 50% of the one in the background? I do not want to re-size the UITextView in the front, but merely to hide half of it.

I think an illustration is in place as this might sound rather confusing:

[image]

I thought I do this with two view controllers, one hidden, one visible:

```
// Visible and Hidden View 

VisibleView *visibleController = [[VisibleView alloc] initWithNibName:@"VisibleView" bundle:nil];
self.visibleView = visibleController;
[visibleController release];

HiddenView *hiddenController = [[HiddenView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HiddenView" bundle:nil];
self.hiddenView = hiddenController;
[hiddenController release];

[self.view insertSubview:visibleView.view atIndex:0]; // show visibleView
```

Ideally, I would like to animate the 'hiding' of the visibleView Controller, so that the hiddenViewController unveils in the background (like a sliding door - sliding in from the right). This is what I've come up so far, but I can't think of any transformation / cropping technique that will do:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Hide VisibleView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];   
[UIView setAnimationTransition: ??
                       forView: self.view
                         cache: YES];
[visibleView.view removeFromSuperview];                 
[self.view insertSubview:hiddenView.view atIndex:0];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I guess this is quite basic, but I'm still a beginner and would be very happy over any suggestions of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created a new View-Based Application project and put this code in the viewDidLoad of the viewController to get the screen shown. It shows the theory of what you need to do. The main points to note are the 'clipsToBounds = true' and the negative x-position of textFrameRight.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f];

    CGRect textFrameLeft = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    UITextView* textLeft = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrameLeft];
    textLeft.text = text;
    textLeft.font = font;
    textLeft.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    CGRect textFrameRight = textFrameLeft;
    textFrameRight.origin.x -= textFrameRight.size.width/2;

    UITextView* textRight = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrameRight];
    textRight.text = text;
    textRight.font = font;
    textRight.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CGRect leftFrame = self.view.frame;
    leftFrame.size.width /= 2;

    UIView* leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:leftFrame];
    leftView.clipsToBounds = true;

    CGRect rightFrame = self.view.frame;
    rightFrame.size.width -= leftFrame.size.width;
    rightFrame.origin.x += leftFrame.size.width;

    UIView* rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rightFrame];
    rightView.clipsToBounds = true;

    [self.view addSubview:leftView];
    [leftView addSubview:textLeft];

    [self.view addSubview:rightView];
    [rightView addSubview:textRight];

    [leftView release];
    [textLeft release];
    [rightView release];
    [textRight release];
}
```

[image: Cropping UITextView]

==================================

Realising the OP wanted this to animate; here is a revised version of the above method which does such. There are more hard-coded values in this version; but it serves as an example.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f];

    CGRect leftFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 480);
    CGRect textFrameLeft = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 480);

    CGRect rightFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    CGRect textFrameRight = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    UITextView* textLeft = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrameLeft];
    textLeft.text = text;
    textLeft.font = font;
    textLeft.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UITextView* textRight = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrameRight];
    textRight.text = text;
    textRight.font = font;
    textRight.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView* leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:leftFrame];
    leftView.clipsToBounds = true;

    UIView* rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rightFrame];
    rightView.clipsToBounds = true;

    [self.view addSubview:leftView];
    [leftView addSubview:textLeft];

    [self.view addSubview:rightView];
    [rightView addSubview:textRight];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Hide VisibleView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    rightView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 0, 480);
    textRight.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480);
    leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    textLeft.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [leftView release];
    [textLeft release];
    [rightView release];
    [textRight release];
}
```

Comment: @Wex: Wow, I am really impressed as well! Thanks for this very lucid and straightforward example. I was so confused about frames etc., but your code explains it better than 1000 words would do. I will try to animate it and post my results once I'm done. Thanks so much again!!

Comment: No problem guys :). I didn't realise you wanted it animated. That should be possible by manipulating leftView.frame and rightView.frame however you need.

Comment: @Wex: I had a go with getting it animated, but I guess I make life too difficult. If I understand the concept, I must change 4 values in order to get this animated from RIGHT TO LEFT (i.e. imagine the red comes from the left, i.e. the text becomes soaked with red/blood from the left). I would need to change the following in my animation:  textFrameRight.origin.x = -320 ----> 0;         
 leftFrame.size.width = 320 -----> 0; 
 rightFrame.size.width = 0 -----> 320; 
 rightFrame.origin.x = 320 ------> 0;

Comment: @Wex: Or is there an easier solution manipulating the frames?

Comment: Updated the answer with another code example that has animation. I should also say: Notice you have to set the .frame property to get the animation to work.

Comment: @Wex. Thanks so much. I've struggled with this, and no, mine didn't work. It does now because I did not realise that I needed to get set the .frame property. You saved my sanity (at least for today, don't know with what problems I will come up tomorrow). You have an extraordinary talent to explain things (with code) - I'm very impressed. Thanks for your time and help. I really, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use to mask view with other views. In your case I'll do something like this:

- both of textviews has its own superview that act as a mask
- animate the frame of each single mask to reveal/hide the children view

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful! Sorry to ask this, but does a textview have a superview or the viewController (e.g. in my case the visibleController)? How do I access the mask of the superview in this instance? Will I need to call something like `mask superview.visibleController.UITextView1`? In other words, how do I access the frame of the mask of the superview of my textview1? Sorry if this is basic, but I'm really struggling. I had a look at the UIView docs, but can't make much sense of it.

Comment: - (textView) it's a textView

- (maskView) it's a basic uiview (clipToBounds:YES) and it has the textView (textView) as subview

Then:
in the viewController I'll do something like this:

[UIView beginAnimation.....]

maskView.frame = cgrectmake(.....)

[UIView commitAnim....]

Comment: I see! Will give this a try and let you know how it went. Thanks so much for your help, I appreciate your explanations.